# web3py ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'unknown account'}

Tags: python, solidity, web3py

I want to send parameter to smart contract using transact method(web3py)
but it wasn't working

Error code is below
"ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'unknown account'}"

Owner address is same definitely
(Owner address deployed by remix == web3py owner address(wal_address))
Has anyone experienced the same issue as me?

Here is my Solidity code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract StakingRewards {
    IERC20 public immutable stakingToken;
    IERC20 public immutable rewardsToken;

    address public owner;

    uint public duration;
    uint public finishAt;
    uint public updatedAt;
    uint public rewardRate;
    uint public rewardPerTokenStored;
    uint public totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint) public userRewardPerTokenPaid;
    mapping(address => uint) public rewards;
    mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;

    constructor(address _stakingToken, address _rewardToken) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        stakingToken = IERC20(_stakingToken);
        rewardsToken = IERC20(_rewardToken);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "not authorized");
        _;
    }

    modifier updateReward(address _account) {
        rewardPerTokenStored = rewardPerToken();
        updatedAt = lastTimeRewardApplicable();

        if (_account != address(0)) {
            rewards[_account] = earned(_account);
            userRewardPerTokenPaid[_account] = rewardPerTokenStored;
        }
        _;
    }

    function lastTimeRewardApplicable() public view returns (uint) {
        return _min(finishAt, block.timestamp);
    }

    function rewardPerToken() public view returns (uint) {
        if (totalSupply == 0) {
            return rewardPerTokenStored;
        }
        return
            rewardPerTokenStored +
            (rewardRate * (lastTimeRewardApplicable() - updatedAt) * 1e18) /
            totalSupply;
    }

    function stake(uint _amount) external updateReward(msg.sender) {
        require(_amount > 0, "amount = 0");
        stakingToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += _amount;
        totalSupply += _amount;
    }

    function withdraw(uint _amount) external updateReward(msg.sender) {
        require(_amount > 0, "amount = 0");
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        totalSupply -= _amount;
        stakingToken.transfer(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    function earned(address _account) public view returns (uint) {
        return
            ((balanceOf[_account] *
                (rewardPerToken() - userRewardPerTokenPaid[_account])) / 1e18) +
            rewards[_account];
    }

    function getReward() external updateReward(msg.sender) {
        uint reward = rewards[msg.sender];
        if (reward > 0) {
            rewards[msg.sender] = 0;
            rewardsToken.transfer(msg.sender, reward);
        }
    }

    function setRewardsDuration(uint _duration) external onlyOwner {
        require(finishAt < block.timestamp, "reward duration not finished");
        duration = _duration;
    }

    function notifyRewardAmount(uint _amount)
        external
        onlyOwner
        updateReward(address(0))
    {
        if (block.timestamp >= finishAt) {
            rewardRate = _amount / duration;
        } else {
            uint remainingRewards = (finishAt - block.timestamp) * rewardRate;
            rewardRate = (_amount + remainingRewards) / duration;
        }

        require(rewardRate > 0, "reward rate = 0");
        require(
            rewardRate * duration <= rewardsToken.balanceOf(address(this)),
            "reward amount > balance"
        );

        finishAt = block.timestamp + duration;
        updatedAt = block.timestamp;
    }

    function _min(uint x, uint y) private pure returns (uint) {
        return x <= y ? x : y;
    }
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}
```

Here is web3 py code

```
from web3 import Web3
import json
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

rpc_url = 'http://...................' ## Custom testnet
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(rpc_url))
web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)  #  Inject poa middleware 


con_address = ".........................................."
wal_address = '..........................................'
                    # with open("/Users/creativelab/Desktop/Source/abi.json") as f:
                    #     info_json = json.load(f)
abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getReward",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "notifyRewardAmount",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_duration",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setRewardsDuration",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "stake",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_stakingToken",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_rewardToken",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "withdraw",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "duration",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_account",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "earned",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "finishAt",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "lastTimeRewardApplicable",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "owner",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "rewardPerToken",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "rewardPerTokenStored",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "rewardRate",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "rewards",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "rewardsToken",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "contract IERC20",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "stakingToken",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "contract IERC20",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "totalSupply",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "updatedAt",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "userRewardPerTokenPaid",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]


contract = web3.eth.contract(address=con_address, abi=abi)
TotalSupply = contract.functions.getReward().call() 

contract.functions.setRewardsDuration(1).transact({'from': wal_address})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import [your private key to web3.py application](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#read-a-private-key-from-an-environment-variable). Then use local signing middleware to sign the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is not a account thing. i got same problem as you got before. to solve the problem you need to change function.

instead of using this code

```
contract.functions.setRewardsDuration(1).transact({'from': wal_address})
```

you have to use this kind of code

```
def functiontransaction(tx):

    signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, privatekey)
    
    tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    
    return w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

tx = contract.functions.setRewardsDuration(1).buildTransaction(
            {
                "from" : wal_address,
            }
        )
tx_receipt = functiontransaction(tx)
```

it because you are using json-rpc protocol and web3, it doesnt support wallet inside protocol, but you are using `sendTransaction` function instead of `sendRawTransaction` so you have to use `sendRawTransaction`
[Difference between sendTransaction and sendRawTransaction in web3.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985798/difference-between-sendtransaction-and-sendrawtransaction-in-web3-py)